# How to get a specific latest transform from lookupTransform

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using `tf2_ros::TransformListener` listening on `/tf` topic, which contains various `target_frame` and `source_frame` pairs. I want to extract only a specific pair, say `IMU` and `TURTLE`. That pair is published at 250Hz according to rqt.

When I call: `buffer.lookupTransform("IMU", "TURTLE", ros::Time(0))` I get `"IMU" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist` exception most of the time, but occasionally a good result.

When I call: `buffer.lookupTransform("IMU", "TURTLE", ros::Time::now())` or `buffer.lookupTransform("IMU", "TURTLE", ros::Time::now()-ros::Duration(0.1))` I get `Lookup would require extrapolation into the future...` or `Lookup would require extrapolation into the past...`

What is a reliable way to retrieve the most current transform with given `target_frame` and `source_frame`?

**EDIT**

The issue was caused by simulation startup delay. `waitForTransform()` as suggested in the answer below is the solution to my problem. Even better is its newer incarnation: `tf2_ros::Buffer::canTransform()`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347149/how-to-get-a-specific-latest-transform-from-lookuptransform/) by [pauljurczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/47807/pauljurczak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2020-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-03-20**:
Please edit your question provide more information about how to reproduce your problem. If the query with time zero is failing it likely means that you are not setting up your `TransformListener` with the right lifecycle to allow it to build up it's cache.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-03-20**:
Glad to hear that worked. Please accept the answer below with the checkbox to let other know this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for, but you could use *waitForTransform* to wait for the transformation to become available.

Check: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html

---

Originally posted by [ir](https://answers.ros.org/users/52711/ir/) with karma: 26 on 2020-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1